# Gaussian Mixture: minvalue must be less than or equal to maxvalue

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mixture-model, gmm

In my exploratory analysis, I am currently using Gaussian Mixture Model to exclude outliers by plotting the contour plot for each phone model (a total of 4 unique models). I am using these 2 variables (`r_max`, `b_max`) to detect whether a point is an outlier.

This is my dataset (180 rows, 4 columns):

```
r_max | b_max | SPAD | model
255.0 | 46.0  | 35.1   | Redmi 5A
198.0 | 36.0  | 32.5   | Vivo 1820
237.0 | 77.0  | 35.8   | CPH1920
255.0 | 79.0  | 30.1   | SM-M105F
```

This is my code to create a contour plot:

```
for ph in final_df.model.unique():

    dataf = final_df[final_df.model==ph]
    
    dataf = dataf[['r_max',  'b_max', 'SPAD', 'model']]

    dataf = dataf[['r_max', 'b_max']].values
    #dataf = np.array(dataf).reshape(-1,1)

    # fit gaussian mixture model 
    gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture()
    gmm.fit(dataf)

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 300), np.linspace(0, 300))
    XX = np.array([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T
    Z = gmm.score_samples(XX)
    Z = Z.reshape(X.shape)
    CS = plt.contour(X, Y, -Z, norm=LogNorm(vmax=500), levels=np.logspace(0, 3, 10))
    CB = plt.colorbar(CS, shrink= 1.0, extend = 'both')
    plt.scatter(dataf[:,0], dataf[:,1], marker = "x", cmap='viridis')
    plt.title(f"{ph} : r_max vs b_max")
    #ax.set_title(f"{feats[idx]} vs SPAD")
    plt.show()
```

I can create the plots for all models except CPH1920. In this line:

```
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, -Z, norm=LogNorm(vmax=500), levels=np.logspace(0, 3, 10))
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: min value must be less than or equal to max value
```

Example of output i get for Redmi 5A:
[image]

**I'm not sure if I am understanding it correctly, but the points outside the purple circle are outliers right?**

**Next question, how do I extract which data points are the outliers?** I would like to know which points are considered outliers, so I can exclude them in my dataset for EDA. Is there some way to calculate the probability of each point being an outlier then set a threshold if >0.5 is an outlier?

Hoping someone can lend some help here, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Probably best to focus on one question at a time.  If you're trying to understand why you get an error for CPH1920, maybe one thing would be to look at summary stats for its r_max and b_max values, and for the Z values.

Comment: You also need to add tags to your question based on what you're using. i.e. pandas, numpy, matplotlib, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice! However, my main question would be how do I extract which data points are classified as outliers according to GMM? I need to know what points are these so I can exclude them in my exploratory analysis.

Answer (score 0):

As requested in the comments I'll only answer the question on how to exclude the outliers. You already used everything you need in your code for the contour plot. The function `gmm.score_samples` takes an array of data points and returns an array of probabilities under the GMM. Now you can simply threshold them as you suggested:

```
threshold = 0.5
probs = gmm.score_samples(dataf)
not_outliers = dataf[probs > threshold]
```

The array `no_outliers` should now only contain the data points above your threshold. You have to experiment a bit on how high you should set it.